# asp-items in the select returning path instead of database result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 2 tables:

```
FoodItem(FoodID,Name,etc..)
Invoice(InvoiceId,FoodId (foreign key of FoodID),etc..)
```

I first created a DbContext and a Model Class Invoice.cs then I added a scaffolded item to the controller where views were created for Create,Delete,Details,Edit and Index for the Invoice.

I am trying for Create.cshtml to put a drop down list for the foreign key FoodId with the Name in the FoodItem table on a dropdown list instead of manually typing an ID.

I have the following:

In InvoicesController I added:

```
 public static List<Invoice> Invoice()
        {
            List<Invoice> jt = new List<Invoice>();
            string connection = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=invoicesystem;Data Source=.;Connection Timeout=100000;";
            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("select FoodItem.Name from FoodItem full join Invoice on Invoice.FoodId=FoodItem.FoodID")) 
                {
                    using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
                        sqlconn.Open();
                        sda.SelectCommand = sqlcomm;

                        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
                        while(sdr.Read())
                        {
                            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
                            invoice.FoodId = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                            jt.Add(invoice);
                        }


                    }

                    return jt;
                }

            }

        }
```

and I added a ViewData in the Create() method in the Controller class by calling the function:

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["Food Name"] = Invoice();
            return View();
        }
```

This is the Model Class I'm using:

```
namespace RoleBaseAuth.Models
{
    public class Invoice
    {
        [Key]
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AspNetUsers")]
        public string  UserId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("FoodItem")]
        public string FoodId{ get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public double totalsum { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In the Create.cshtml file , I defined the variable using ViewData and replaced the regular  for the FoodId to a select list in the following format:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    var invoice = (List<Invoice>)ViewData["Food Name"];
}

<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FoodId" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="FoodId" class="form-control" asp-items='new SelectList(invoice,"Name")'></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="FoodId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

I'm getting this result:
[image: Actual Result]

Comment: What did you expect? `Invoice.ToString()` is `RoleBaseAuth.Models.Invoice`. Either you override the ToString method in your invoice or you tell Razor which of the Invoice property to display.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner at this, how to make it display the actual database results?
@LegacyCode

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
1-create a class named DrpItems in models
 public class DrpItems
 {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int FoodId {get;set;}
  }
2-change the list type
List<DrpItems> jt = new List<DrpItems>();
3-Change your query
 using (SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("select distinct FoodItem.FoodId as FoodId,FoodItem.Name as Name from FoodItem full join Invoice on Invoice.FoodId=FoodItem.FoodID")) 
4- public static List<DrpItems> Invoice()
5-change loop
            while(sdr.Read())
                        {
                            DrpItems item = new DrpItems();
                            item.FoodId = sdr["FoodId"];
                item.Name = sdr["Name"];
                            jt.Add(item);
                        }



6-
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    var invoice = ViewData["Food Name"] as RoleBaseAuth.Models.DrpItems;
}

   <select asp-for="Location" asp-items="(SelectList)@ViewData["Food Name"]" class="form-control" ></select>

or
 <select asp-for="FoodId" 
            asp-items="@(new SelectList(invoice,"FoodId","Name"))">
        <option>Please select one</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change like below:

```
<select asp-for="FoodId" class="form-control" asp-items='new SelectList(invoice,"FoodId","FoodId")'></select>
```